# Target "run" does not exist in the project "barbecue"

Tags: ant, jasper-reports

I want to run a sample demo for JasperReport, so I downloaded the file but when I type the following in my windows 7 command line [according to the Jasperreport documentation](http://jasperforge.org/website/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/documentation.html?header=project&target=jasperreports) :

```
C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\barbecue>ant run
```

I got the following error:

> Target "run" does not exist in the project "barbecue" .

So what might be the problem ?

**::UPDATED::**
After i typed `ant –p` in my CMD i got the following :-

```
C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\barbecue>ant -p
Buildfile: C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\barbecue\build.xml
Shows how barcodes could be included in reports using the Barbecue component.
Main targets:

 clean          Deletes all the generated files.
 compile        Compiles the XML report design and produces the .jasper file.
 csv            Generates a CSV version of the report by converting the .jrprint
 file.
 decompile      Decompiles a .jasper file into a .jrxml file.
 docx           Generates a DOCX version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
 fill           Fills the compiled report design with data and produces the .jrp
rint file.
 html           Generates an HTML version of the report by converting the .jrpri
nt file.
 javac          Compiles the java source files of the test application.
 jxl            Generates an XLS version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file using the JExcelApi library.
 ods            Generates an ODS version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
 odt            Generates an ODT version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
 pdf            Generates a PDF version of the report by converting the .jrprint
 file.
 pptx           Generates a PPTX version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
 print          Sends the report in the .jrprint file to the printer.
 rtf            Generates an RTF version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
 test           Runs the sample.
 view           Launches the report viewer to preview the report stored in the .
jrprint file.
 viewDesign     Launches the design viewer to preview the compiled report design
.
 viewDesignXml  Launches the design viewer to preview the XML report design.
 viewXml        Launches the report viewer to preview the generated report store
d in an XML file.
 writeApi       Generates a .java version of the report by converting the .jrxml
 file.
 writeApiXml    Generates a .jrxml version of the report by executing the API ve
rsion of the report design.
 xhtml          Generates an XHTML version of the report by converting the .jrpr
int file.
 xls            Generates an XLS version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file using the POI library.
 xlsx           Generates an XLSX version of the report by converting the .jrpri
nt file.
 xml            Generates an XML version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
 xmlEmbed       Generates an XML version of the report by converting the .jrprin
t file.
Default target: test
```

**:::::UPDATED2:::::**
i type `ant test` for the charts demo but the problem is still there:-

```
C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts>ant test
Buildfile: C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\build.xml

test:
     [echo] ===================================
     [echo]  Charts Sample
     [echo] ===================================

clean:

clean-sample:

javac:

javac:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\build\classe
s
    [javac] C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\build.xml:41: warning: 'includea
ntruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for
repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\char
ts\build\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with
-source 1.6
    [javac] Note: C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\src\ChartsApp.java
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 warning
     [copy] Copied 5 empty directories to 5 empty directories under C:\jasperrep
orts-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\build\classes

compile:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\build\report
s
      [jrc] Compiling 24 report design files.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\MultipleAx
isChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\XYBarChart
TimePeriodReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\XYAreaChar
tReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\Pie3DChart
Report.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\StackedBar
3DChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\MeterChart
Report.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\XYBarChart
Report.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\StackedAre
aChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\Candlestic
kChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\HighLowCha
rtReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\XYLineChar
tReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\BubbleChar
tReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\Thermomete
rChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\StackedBar
ChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\ScatterCha
rtReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\TimeSeries
ChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\SubDataset
ChartReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\AreaChartR
eport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\LineChartR
eport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\XYBarChart
TimeSeriesReport.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\GanttChart
Report.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\PieChartRe
port.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\Bar3DChart
Report.jrxml ... OK.
      [jrc] File : C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\reports\BarChartRe
port.jrxml ... OK.

test:
     [java] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: sock
et creation error
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.AbstractSampleApp.getDemoHsq
ldbConnection(AbstractSampleApp.java:158)
     [java]     at ChartsApp.fill(ChartsApp.java:83)
     [java]     at ChartsApp.test(ChartsApp.java:63)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:57)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMet
hodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.AbstractSampleApp.executeTas
k(AbstractSampleApp.java:94)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.AbstractSampleApp.main(Abstr
actSampleApp.java:179)
     [java]     at ChartsApp.main(ChartsApp.java:54)
     [java] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
     [java]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
     [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.AbstractSampleApp.getDemoHsq
ldbConnection(AbstractSampleApp.java:150)
     [java]     ... 9 more

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds

C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts>ant run
Buildfile: C:\jasperreports-4.7.0\demo\samples\charts\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "run" does not exist in the project "charts".

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run *`ant test`* command for run the sample (cleaning, compiling and generating the report in all formats: xls, pdf, etc.).

For viewing report in ***JRViewer*** you should run *`ant view`* command.

The result (output) for *`ant test`* will be:

```
d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\barbecue>ant test
Buildfile: d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\barbecue\build.xml

test:
     [echo] ===================================
     [echo]  Barbecue Sample
     [echo] ===================================

clean:

clean-sample:

javac:

javac:
    [mkdir] Created dir: d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\barbecue\build
\classes
    [javac] d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\build.xml:41: warning: 'inc
ludeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false
 for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\
barbecue\build\classes

compile:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\barbecue\build
\reports
      [jrc] Compiling 1 report design files.
      [jrc] File : d:\java\jasperreports-4.5.1\demo\samples\barbecue\reports\Bar
becueReport.jrxml ... OK.

test:
     [java] Filling time : 3198
     [java] PDF creation time : 993
     [java] XML creation time : 224
     [java] XML creation time : 44
     [java] HTML creation time : 109
     [java] RTF creation time : 98
     [java] XLS creation time : 364
     [java] XLS creation time : 248
     [java] CSV creation time : 6
     [java] ODT creation time : 95
     [java] ODS creation time : 12
     [java] DOCX creation time : 183
     [java] XLSX creation time : 103
     [java] PPTX creation time : 74
     [java] XHTML creation time : 56

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13 seconds
```

---

***The reaction on the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: sock
et creation error` exception:***

The sample that you are trying to start is using connection to the *HSQLDB* server. For starting DB you should run *`ant runServer`* command from the *`demo/hsqldb`* folder.

For more details how to run sample you can read [this post](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/charts/index.html#charts)

Comment: thanks for the reply,, i tried ant test but the same issue will remain. see my second update to my original question .

Comment: You should firstly start the DB - I've add info how to run it.

Comment: thanks for the reply,,, i type "ant run" and it gave me "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", but when i type "ant run" it will raise the following error:- 
BUILD FAILED
Target "run" does not exist in the project "barbecue". So is this normal?

Comment: @johnpoal Yes, it is normal, because there is no ***run*** target in *build.xml* file located in *`demo\samples\barbecue`* folder.

Answer (score 3):

Java errors are like a car accident. One car will hit another which causes the first to careen into a street light. The street light topples over and hits a gasoline truck which explodes.

In the end, you have destruction, fire, and death. However, the whole thing started because the driver was too busy texting and didn't stop at a stop sign.

You have a long, long list of error messages, but what's important are those at the very beginning:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.AbstractSampleApp.getDemoHsqldbConnection(AbstractSampleApp.java:158)
```

This is a *socket creation error*.

This error seems to point out that you can't connect to the server or the database.

And, that's about as far as I can get with this. I really don't know Jasper, but I did find [this](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=86819). Does that help you at all?

Is there a server you should be running, or a database you need to connect to that's not created? Do you have a firewall that's preventing connecting to the server/database. (I'm leaning towards the database issue because I do see stuff about *hsqldb* and *sql* in your error message.

I take it you're not a Java developer because you seemed confused by Ant and it's *build.xml* file. Is there someone who can help you with this? If you can, look at the *build.xml* and see what the target *test* is doing. It's running a Java command, and you can try running that command outside of Ant. Sometimes, that will give you a bit more information.